# Blowfish encryption algorithm explained

Tags: c++, encryption, encryption-symmetric, blowfish

I have hard times implementing [blowfish encryption algorythm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29#C.2B.2B_implementation).

Could someone explain to me,
if this is the function where the encrypting happens:

```
 void encrypt (uint32_t & L, uint32_t & R) {
    for (int i=0 ; i<16 ; i += 2) {
       L ^= P[i];
       R ^= f(L);
       R ^= P[i+1];
       L ^= f(R);
    }
    L ^= P[16];
    R ^= P[17];
    swap (L, R);
 }
```

so how would a function like this would look like:

```
/**
*
* @param string text this is the text to be encrypted
* @return string this is encrypted text 
*/
string EncryptBlowfish(string text){
    //something happens here
}
```

Comment: Blowfish is probably the easiest and most elegant encryption to understand.

Comment: If you read the `key_schedule` function of the link you provided, you would see where the encryption occurs.  The `encrypt` function operating on 2 consecutive words in the block.

Comment: The code is just so hard to undertstand out of the box, and i had not found any any exaples to read smoothly. Have you got any @ZacHowland

Comment: @user3325976 I would recommend you invest in [Applied Cryptography](http://www.amazon.com/Applied-Cryptography-Protocols-Algorithms-Source/dp/0471117099) to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should review the existing encryption library interfaces and the theoretical description of Blowfish to get a better understanding how these implementation have been done before, including the design of the interface. To design a good interface you need to source a decent a number of use cases for your code, and in the absence of that data sample, unique to your case, you should fall back to the already common wisdom.

For instance, take a look at [crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Blowfish) page for blowfish (and scroll down to the end of the page to skip streams and filters where it shows usage of an encryptor that can be fed individual bytes).

Taking that example forward, your code *can* look like this:

```
class StatefulBlowfish {    
private:
   BlowfishKey key_;
   BlowfishIv iv_;
public:    
void EncryptCBC(string text, /*out*/ byte*){
   for (int i=0; I < text.size(); i++) {
      // process and xor an individual ‘(byte)text[i]’ the 
      // necessary number of rounds. Consider padding.
  }
  ...    
}
```

But such a class isn’t very generic and has a lot of fixed parts which can make it harder to test, use and maintain. Another important thing to consider is that the interface that you have to design isn’t restricted to taking a string to encrypt, as you suggest in the question, but rather have to account for the chaining mode, the key and the iv – they are best to be created and managed elsewhere, to adhere to single responsibility principle.

You should also strive to have arrays or pointers to arrays of bytes as the interface of your low-level encryptor methods, because this is how the algorithm operates, and ideally the serialisation from a string to an array of bytes (and vice versa) should be offloaded to a separate interface. (Consider for example the assumptions on a “string” between big and little endian architectures, or the requirements on padding.)

A good generic OOP design is on one hand a collection of encryption "parts" each having more or less a single responsibility (serialisation, padding, chaining mode, key initialisation, key schedule, etc) and on the other hand a good design admits an easy creation of a bigger chain of responsibility construct, that describes the intention from simply observing the code.

Coming full circle back to cryptopp, modifying a standard code example for a slightly better clarity, look how everything is handled separately:

```
// a key is created, to be separately initialised with a PRNG
// or from a secure source, hardware TRNG, etc.
SecByteBlock key(Blowfish::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH); 
...
// an iv is created, similarly to be separately initialised with a PRNG
byte iv[Blowfish::BLOCKSIZE]; 
...
// Wrap blowfish low-level implementation in a CBC chaining mode 
// and initialise it with the key and iv    
CBC_Mode<Blowfish>::Encryption e; 
e.SetKeyWithIV(key, key.size(), iv);    
...    
// have a separate padding wrapper
... new StreamTransformationFilter(e, /*out*/ cipher)
```